# Jquery dialog box problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok so I have setup my own dialogbox and have put a text box and a button in the dialog box. What I am trying to do is have them enter in the info in the text box and then it would autofill my form on the next page after I closed the dialog box. I am having issues with the autofill part. Any ideas? Here is my dialog box and my form name is shipping.

```
showDialog(
   '<p>Enter in Non Client Job Code</p>
    <div class="margin-top"><input type="text" size="15" name="projectnumber" id="projectnumber" value="" /><br />
    <input type="button" onclick="fillin()" value="Enter" />'
);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the code you provided lacks context and is really not useful to those of us who can't see the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will fix things, but you're missing a closing  tag.

```
showDialog('
    <p>Enter in Non Client Job Code</p>
    <div class="margin-top">
        <input type="text" size="15" name="projectnumber" id="projectnumber" value="" />
        <br />
        <input type="button" onclick="fillin()" value="Enter" />
    </div>
');
```

Comment: Was it just the closing div tag? And I get it to call that function just fine it is just autofilling that form from the function too.